# Output a list of integers in two separate lanes

Tags: integer, output, line

I'm just started coding and I don't know how to output afficheAaB and afficheAaB(a,b) into two separate lines. At the moment, a simgle line with all the numbers. Ex.: a = 3   b = 11 (3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 3 5 7 9 11). I want to separate the two into (3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11) and (3 5 7 9 11). Thank you in advance!

```
def afficheAaB(a,b):
    for nombre in range(a,b+1):
        reponse1 = print(nombre,"", end="")
    return reponse1      
                   
def afficheAaBpas2(a,b):
    for nombre in range(a,b+1,2):
        reponse2 = print(nombre,"", end="")
    return reponse2

a = int(input("SVP donner la valeur de a: "))
b = int(input("SVP donner la valeur de b: "))

afficheAaB = afficheAaB(a,b)    
afficheAaBpas2 = afficheAaBpas2(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to leave a new line between the 2 methods by printing a new line character ('\n'). Another solution would be just to call print with empty arguments. This by default prints a new line.
For example, you can update the last 2 lines with following:

```
afficheAaB = afficheAaB(a,b) 
print()   
afficheAaBpas2 = afficheAaBpas2(a,b)
```

If you want to understand what caused this behavior of not printing new lines between the 2 functions please check **print** [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp). In short when you add **end=""** you specify what you want to print at the end of your command. By default, we print a newline character but you have replaced that in your code with an empty string.